# how to use self defined function mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use a self-defined function in mongodb to calculate some values, but have no clue on how to use it.
There are avgStartLongitude, avgStartLatitudes, avgEndLongitude and avgEndLatitude. Grouped by an activity. It shows the location of an activity which started and ended somewhere. I need to calculate the distance between them by using a function.

This is the collection from where the calculation needs to be done:http://prntscr.com/d3cn4m

Following code shows (in a way that does not work) how I try to use the function to calculate:

```js
function calcDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = 
     0.5 - Math.cos(dLat)/2 + 
     Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * 
     (1 - Math.cos(dLon))/2;

  return (R * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)))<100;
};

db.opg3.aggregate(
{
    $project:
    {
        activityType:"$_id",
        avgDistance:"$calcDistance($avgStartLat,$avgStartLon,$avgEndLat,$avgEndLon)"
        
    }
    
}
)
```

The code does not return the avgDistance. In fact it seems to do nothing and I have no clue how to make it work..

Any ideas on how I should use this function?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try doing calculation in the query itself ?

Comment: you can't use javascript function in aggregation pipeline. For this you should go with map reduce, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496679/using-stored-javascript-functions-in-the-aggregation-pipeline-mapreduce-or-runc for details