# MongoDB aggregate, using project computed field, and sorting with this field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to do this using MongoDB aggregation-framework, is this possible?

```
db.objects.aggregate([
    {$match:
        {$and:[
              {location:{$nearSphere:{$geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[latitude, longitude]},$minDistance:x,$maxDistance:y}}},

              {date1:{$gte:date2}
              ]
        }
    },
    {$project:ratio
        {$divide:[
                 {$subtract:[date1,date2]},

                 {result of a function returning distance between this location and latitude, longitude in parameters}
                 ]
        }
    },
    {$sort:{ratio:-1}}
]);
```

Is this possible to do this with db.collection.group({ key, reduce, initial [, keyf] [, cond] [, finalize] }) ?...

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that. Anyway you don't need to use the `$and` operator on the first `$match`, the two conditions are in `$and` by default. Just write `$match: { location: { ... }, date1: { ... } }`. Also in your `$project` you must define `ratio` as an object key: `$project: { ratio: {$divide ... } }`.

Comment: And how to call the function returning distance ?...

Comment: You can define javascript functions to use in queries, take a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497321/10026557). For an algorithm to calculate distance between two lat long coordinates you can check this one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/10026557)

Comment: Can we see whether it's possible to do what you function is doing with the Aggregation Framework?

Comment: I see you can’t call a javascript function with the aggregation framework, it’s not possible. But you can with map reduce...